How to know if certain path homotopy classes generate fundamental group
I am studying for a topology final and came across the following problem.

Let $B^{2} = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid x^{2} + y^{2} \leq 1\}$ denote the unit ball. Consider the space $Y := B^{2} \setminus \{(-\frac{1}{4}, 0), (\frac{1}{4}, 0)\}$ and $\gamma_{\pm}\colon I \rightarrow Y$ given by \begin{align*} & \gamma_{+}(t) = \frac{1}{4}(1-\cos(2\pi t), -\sin(2\pi t)) \\ & \gamma_{-}(t) = \frac{1}{4}(\cos(2\pi t) - 1, \sin(2\pi t)).\end{align*}
Do $[\gamma_{+}]$ and $[\gamma_{-}]$ generate the fundamental group $\pi_{1}(Y, (0, 0))$?

I've sketched $Y$, $\gamma_{+}$ and $\gamma_{-}$, which show the unit circle with two punctures and two circles with radius $\frac{1}{4}$ centered at those punctures respectively. Furthermore, I've shown that $Y$ is homotopy equivalent to the figure eight space.
I'm having trouble understanding how the homotopy classes could generate the fundamental group, if at all. My intuition says that they do not generate the fundamental group, it seems that some loops based at the origin are not 'multiples' of $\gamma_{+}$ and $\gamma_{-}$ (up to continuous deformation). But I'm not sure how to show this.
Any help is appreciated.

Do you know the fundamental group of the figure eight?

I recall now that this is related to the Seifert van Kampen theorem, thank you.
